# Ruby and Twitter What is the correct way to post for multiple accounts?

Tags: ruby, twitter

im building an app very similar to CoTweet. I have many twitter accounts (all of mine) and i want to reply to mentions using the right account.

Im REALLY NEW to ruby. Can I use username / password authentication? i found some instructions to do this on internet but appears to be for a OLD twitter gem version.

If i use oauth can i use many accounts at the same time?

What is the variables I have to store in my DB to use oauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than you may think, all you need to do is to use the Twitter [gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) and it will take care of the rest for you. For multi-account setup, you will have to create a separate `Twitter::Client` for each of your accounts, as described [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/wiki/Configuration).